# Setting keyframes with default linear interpolation

Tags: animation, customization

Is there a way to add keyframes (<kbd>I</kbd> key) with **LINEAR interpolation** as default instead of **BEZIER**?

I often animate cyclic motion (e.g. planets orbiting around the sun or textures spinning about Z on a sphere) and the created f-curves have BEZIER as default interpolation. This requires me to immediately change the interpolation to LINEAR.

I was wondering if there is a magic key that I can use to have the keyframes added as LINEAR interpolated, or at least have a global setting that I can set to have LINEAR interpolation used by default.

Comment: Please search around the site before asking a question. There's a good possibility it has been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also prefer Linear interpolation for my initial keyframes, and set is as the default for new keyframe points through *User Preferences* > *New F-Curve Defaults* > *Interpolation*:

[image: 1a]

Comment: In case somebody finds this reply now many years later, like I did: It is in a slightly different place now (but not hard to find): Preferences > Animation > F-Curves .